# BSD jail availability in the event of NFS server failure

Tags: nfs, jail, bsd

I have some BSD systems where I am considering the use of jails for processes that should be isolated from the rest of the system.
The host system has some NFS mounts, and there is the issue that in the event of an NFS server failure, a NFS client tends to become unresponsive.

Would a jail be OK, so long as no affected path was mounted, or unresponsive if an NFS server that the host had mounted went down?